# How to replace token(bearer) with username, password in Cherwell REST API request

Tags: python, rest, curl

I am trying to create RFC in cherwell using REST API in Python. I tried first in Swegger UI. I got it working there. I am able to create RFC successfully. Then by following that Curl Request, in python, using request module, I tried and got 401. I found it why i am getting 401. It's because of in Authorization i am using Bearer which is a temporary token. It will live only for 10 minutes. If i do request after 10 minutes i got a 401. Bearer is a compulsory field. I can't make a request without it. I tried to pass username and password instead of Bearer, it didn't work. below is my request,

```
with open('C:\Cherwell\payload.json') as file:
Data = json.load(file)
payload = Data
header = {"Authorization":"Bearer XXXXXXXX"}
r = requests.post("https:/URL/CherwellAPI/api/V1/savebusinessobject?
api_key=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX", auth=('user','pass'), headers = header, 
data=json.dumps(payload))
print r
```

It will be great, if anyone can help who have done this before! Please Advice

Appreciate any help!

Comment: The requests [Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) module will help you juggle the headers like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210484/flurry-login-requests-session-python-3/39301685#39301685 No need to save the json to disk. The typical pattern is to: try request, catch error if the token is stale, make request to get a fresh token, try again. Or you can use something like Alf to take care of it for you https://github.com/globocom/alf#workflow

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found a work around with it. I make another call and request token. Using that token i can make this request to create RFC.

Answer (score 2):

Found this solution that I used to address a similar problem.  It's a function that requests a token from /CherwellAPI/token and returns a properly formatted Bearer token.  You need to pass this Bearer token along in API requests as a Authorization parameter in the API header.  Should look like token=bearer_token.

```
import json
import requests

configFile = 'config.json'

with open(configFile) as cf:
    config_data = json.load(cf)

def getCherwellToken():
    params = {'apikey' : config_data['cherwell']['client_id']}

    data = {'grant_type' : 'password',
            'client_id' : config_data['cherwell']['client_id'],
            'username' : config_data['cherwell']['username'],
            'password' : config_data['cherwell']['password']}

    url = 'https://.cherwellondemand.com/CherwellAPI/token'

    session = requests.post(url=url, data=data)

    if session:
        token = json.loads(session.text)
    else:
        token = None

    return 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']
```

Answer (score 1):

using another call **Get Token** You can get access token and using that you can request to create a new ticket. This worked for me.